# piped sed fails to do substitution

Tags: bash, sed

I've some files with non-ascii characted that I would like to remove. I'm trying to replace those characters with '-' in the filenames but It doesn't work.

This is my command

```
ls Argi* | xargs -I file basename file '.eps' | sed "s/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/-/"
```

also tryed:

```
ls Argi* | xargs -I file basename file '.eps' | sed "s/\W/-/"
```

Any clue why is not it working?

Comment: If nothing else, you'll want a `g` modifier on the end of the `sed` command to replace all occurrences rather than just the first.

Comment: Well it was a character encoding issue. I've placed an `iconv` command between `xargs` and `sed` and then I've been able to see and replace the faulty characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what do you want for

> replace those characters with '-' in the filenames

I guess you just want to get an output without those characters instead of renaming the original file. because your sed command doesn't do the rename at all.

then you could try iconv:

```
kent$  l
-rw-r--r-- 1 kent kent  0 2012-07-03 12:20 Argiö.eps
-rw-r--r-- 1 kent kent  0 2012-07-03 12:20 Argiü.eps


kent$  ls Argi*|iconv -f utf8 -t ascii//TRANSLIT 
Argio.eps
Argiu.eps
```

this would not replace those letters with "-", but with ASCII.

Comment: Changing `-f utf8` to `-f iso-8859-1` in `iconv` also do the work. Good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`prename`](http://man.he.net/man1/prename) command you likely have on your system. It may be called `rename`, but there's [another program](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename) by that name that works differently.

```
prename 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/-/' Argi*
```